# ESP32 Bluetooth, BLE and WIFI connection data transfer using android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I am Deciding to create an android app using java in android studio to connect, send and receive data using ESP32 with all the available connection methods that is Bluetooth classic, Bluetooth low energy and wifi . Can anyone share any resources or Source codes?

did try some android apps but either not working or slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the official [Android Development Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide). You will find many topics covered, especially interesting for you will be

- the guide to [Bluetooth Classic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth)
- the guide to [Bluetooth Low Energy](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/ble-overview)
- the guide to [Wi-Fi](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-permissions)

The guides offer you a good start on these topics. There are many more independent guides online, sometimes even providing a sample app

Comment: I have checked, it's good but sometimes confusing for me mostly in the BLE case , currently looking on to sample apps
thanks!

Comment: BLE is not really easy, that's true. I've had great success with the [guide by martijn van welie](https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-1-a736dcd53b02)